# Count Even and Odd Numbers User has Inputted - java

Tags: java

Hi this is what a question on a course I am doing wants...

1. The program prints "Type numbers” until the user types the number
   -1. When the user types the number -1, the program prints "Thank you and see you later!" and ends
2. the program should print the sum of the numbers entered by the user
   (without the number -1).
3. the program should print how many numbers the user typed (without
   the number -1).
4. the program should print the average of the numbers the user typed
   (without the number -1).

   **5. the program should print the number of even and odd numbers that the
   user typed (without the number -1).**

I have completed 1-4 but am completely stuck on 5. I did make a start on trying to work it out including putting a for loop inside my while loop but apart from the fact it didnt work it looked well out of place so i removed it. Anyway here is what i have done so far which as I say all works in its own magical way.

And so if anyone can **help me with question 5** that would be great. ps.I'm sure what i've done so far could have been written better but don't focus on that for now cos for me and where i am with Java this is nothing short of a miracle.x

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopsEndingRemembering { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 1;  // to counteract the -1 from the user
        int total = 0;
        double avg;
        //int even = 0;
        //int odd = 0;

        System.out.println("Type numbers:");

        while (true) {
            int numbers = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

            sum += numbers;
            total++;
            avg = ((double) sum) / (total - 1);

            if (numbers == -1) {

                System.out.println("Thank you and see you later!");
                System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
                System.out.println("How many numbers: " + (total - 1));
                System.out.println("Average: " + avg);
                //System.out.println("Even numbers: " + even);
                //System.out.println("Odd numbers: " + odd);
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a hint, lookup this symbol. %

Comment: It might be fun to figure out why this would work: `odd += number & 1`. Of course, you don't need `even` - it is always `total - odd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store variables where one counts odd numbers and one counts even numbers. If the number is odd, increment the odd numbers variable. If even, increment the even numbers variable. Use the % operator to get the remainder of the input divided by 2.

```
int oddNumbers = 0;
int evenNumbers = 0;

if(numbers % 2 == 1){
    oddNumbers++;
} else if(numbers % 2 == 0){
    evenNumbers++;
}
```

Comment: Hi Slenderton thanks for your reply. I did have something like that already but I couldnt work out where in my code it needs to go. Any ideas?

Comment: If you uncomment your variables, the if statements should be added under the line `avg = ((double) sum) / (total - 1);`

Comment: OK I sorted it. I put what you gave me just inside the while loop. I think the mistake i was making i was putting code inside the if statement - if (numbers == -1) {.

Comment: Nice One, easy when you know how

Comment: That would make sense. Also, ensure that you check that the value of `numbers` when it equals -1 isn't added to the odd variable, because `-1 % 2` evaluates to 1, so it would count as an extra odd number.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner in= new Scanner (System.in);
   int sum = 0;
   System.out.print("Enter limit number: ");
   int limit = in.nextInt();
   int oddNumbers = 0;
   int evenNumbers = 0;

   for(int i= 1;i<=limit;i++)
   {
       System.out.println("Enter limit number: "+i+"");
       int numbers= in.nextInt();

       if(numbers %2==0)
       {
           evenNumbers++;
       }
       else if(numbers %2==1)
       {
           oddNumbers++;
       }
   }
   System.out.println("There are: "+oddNumbers+" odd numbers");
   System.out.println("There are :"+evenNumbers+" even numbers");

       }

   }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int firstnum = 4;
        int lastnum = 104;
        int evncnt, oddcnt;
        int count;


        System.out.println("First number is " + firstnum);
        System.out.println("Last number is " + lastnum);

        count = lastnum - firstnum + 1;

        System.out.println("Total numbers are " + count);

        if (count % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Total even numbers are " + count / 2);
                System.out.println("Total odd numbers are " + count / 2);

        } else {
            if (firstnum % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Total Even numbers are ");
                System.out.println((count + 1) / 2);

                System.out.println("Total Odd numbers are ");

                System.out.println((count - 1) / 2);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Total even numbers are ");
                System.out.println((count - 1) / 2);
                System.out.println("Total odd numbers are ");

                System.out.println((count + 1) / 2);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid "code-only" answers; explain what you are doing. And then: there is a **preview** functionality that you should use to ensure that **all** of your code is properly formatted/indented; instead of dropping such a mess on people.